# Querying events from google calendar api by multiple emails

Tags: angular, typescript, google-calendar-api

I am using the google calendar API in my project (Angular in my case).
My problem is that I have a situation in which I need to query events by multiple emails in one request.
By using the "q" field in the request - which represents a free search, I can only search for events by one term- in my case, it means one email.

Example for my request:

```
gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
'calendarId': 'primary',
'maxResults': '9999999',
'q': 'xxx@gmail.com' (and here I want to put more than one email but I can't!)
})
```

Can I use this field or is there any other way in which I can get events by multiple emails in one request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
'q': 'xxx@gmail.com'
```

#### To:

```
'q': 'xxx@gmail.com mail2@gmail.com mail3@gmail.com'
```

- In this case, those emails are used as "AND". When you want to use these emails as "OR", it is required to request them as each request.

#### Note:

- In this case, `q` is used as the query parameter. So, when you add a lot of emails and when an error related to the length of the URL occurs, please split the requests. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)

Comment: So from what you're saying, if I want to use this parameter as "or" state, I have to make request for each email. That's exactly my problem. Thank you very much!